# Configuring an express server to serve my webpack production site

Tags: javascript, angular, express, webpack

I've been working on an Angular 2/Webpack project that I bought through a template which already had a webpack development and production server. They go as followed:

webpack.config.js:

```
// Look in ./config folder for webpack.dev.js
switch (process.env.NODE_ENV) {
  case 'prod':
  case 'production':
    module.exports = require('./config/webpack.prod')({env: 'production'});
    break;
  case 'dev':
  case 'development':
  default:
    module.exports = require('./config/webpack.dev')({env: 'development'});
}
```

webpack.common.js:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const helpers = require('./helpers');

/*
 * Webpack Plugins
 */
// problem with copy-webpack-plugin
const AssetsPlugin = require('assets-webpack-plugin');
const NormalModuleReplacementPlugin = require('webpack/lib/NormalModuleReplacementPlugin');
const ContextReplacementPlugin = require('webpack/lib/ContextReplacementPlugin');
const CommonsChunkPlugin = require('webpack/lib/optimize/CommonsChunkPlugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const CheckerPlugin = require('awesome-typescript-loader').CheckerPlugin;
const HtmlElementsPlugin = require('./html-elements-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const LoaderOptionsPlugin = require('webpack/lib/LoaderOptionsPlugin');
const ScriptExtHtmlWebpackPlugin = require('script-ext-html-webpack-plugin');

/*
 * Webpack Constants
 */
const HMR = helpers.hasProcessFlag('hot');
const AOT = helpers.hasNpmFlag('aot');
const METADATA = {
  title: 'Sing App 3.2.0 with Angular 2.0 Final Release support by Flatlogic',
  baseUrl: '/',
  isDevServer: helpers.isWebpackDevServer()
};

/*
 * Webpack configuration
 *
 * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#cli
 */
module.exports = function(options) {
  isProd = options.env === 'production';
  return {

    /*
     * Cache generated modules and chunks to improve performance for multiple incremental builds.
     * This is enabled by default in watch mode.
     * You can pass false to disable it.
     *
     * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#cache
     */
     //cache: false,

    /*
     * The entry point for the bundle
     * Our Angular.js app
     *
     * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#entry
     */
    entry: {
      'polyfills': './src/polyfills.browser.ts',
      'vendor':    './src/vendor.browser.ts',
      'main':      AOT ? './src/main.browser.aot.ts' :
        './src/main.browser.ts'
    },

    /*
     * Options affecting the resolving of modules.
     *
     * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve
     */
    resolve: {

      /*
       * An array of extensions that should be used to resolve modules.
       *
       * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-extensions
       */
      extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.json'],

      // An array of directory names to be resolved to the current directory
      modules: [helpers.root('src'), helpers.root('node_modules')]

    },

    /*
     * Options affecting the normal modules.
     *
     * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#module
     */
    module: {

      /*
       * An array of automatically applied loaders.
       *
       * IMPORTANT: The loaders here are resolved relative to the resource which they are applied to.
       * This means they are not resolved relative to the configuration file.
       *
       * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#module-loaders
       */
      rules: [
        /*
         * Typescript loader support for .ts and Angular 2 async routes via .async.ts
         * Replace templateUrl and stylesUrl with require()
         *
         * See: https://github.com/s-panferov/awesome-typescript-loader
         * See: https://github.com/TheLarkInn/angular2-template-loader
         */
        {
          test: /\.ts$/,
          use: [
            '@angularclass/hmr-loader?pretty=' + !isProd + '&prod=' + isProd,
            'awesome-typescript-loader?{configFileName: "tsconfig.webpack.json"}',
            'angular2-template-loader',
            'angular-router-loader?loader=system&genDir=compiled/src/app&aot=' + AOT
          ],
          exclude: [/\.(spec|e2e)\.ts$/]
        },

        /*
         * Json loader support for *.json files.
         *
         * See: https://github.com/webpack/json-loader
         */
        {
          test: /\.json$/,
          use: 'json-loader'
        },

        { test: /\.scss$/, use: ['raw-loader', 'sass-loader'] },

        { test: /\.(woff2?|ttf|eot|svg)$/, use: 'url?limit=10000&name=[name].[ext]' },

        // Bootstrap 4
        { test: /bootstrap\/dist\/js\/umd\//, use: 'imports?jQuery=jquery' },

        /*
         * to string and css loader support for *.css files
         * Returns file content as string
         *
         */
        {
          test: /\.css$/,
          use: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader']
        },

        /* Raw loader support for *.html
         * Returns file content as string
         *
         * See: https://github.com/webpack/raw-loader
         */
        {
          test: /\.html$/,
          use: 'raw-loader',
          exclude: [helpers.root('src/index.html')]
        },

        /* File loader for supporting images, for example, in CSS files.
        */
        {
          test: /\.(jpg|png|gif)$/,
          use: 'file-loader'
        },
        {
          noParse: [
            /aws-sdk/,
          ]
        }
      ]
    },

    /*
     * Add additional plugins to the compiler.
     *
     * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#plugins
     */
    plugins: [
      new AssetsPlugin({
        path: helpers.root('dist'),
        filename: 'webpack-assets.json',
        prettyPrint: true
      }),

      /*
       * Plugin: ForkCheckerPlugin
       * Description: Do type checking in a separate process, so webpack don't need to wait.
       *
       * See: https://github.com/s-panferov/awesome-typescript-loader#forkchecker-boolean-defaultfalse
       */
      new CheckerPlugin(),
      /*
       * Plugin: CommonsChunkPlugin
       * Description: Shares common code between the pages.
       * It identifies common modules and put them into a commons chunk.
       *
       * See: https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#commonschunkplugin
       * See: https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/optimization#multi-page-app
       */
      new CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: ['polyfills', 'vendor'].reverse()
      }),

      /**
       * Plugin: ContextReplacementPlugin
       * Description: Provides context to Angular's use of System.import
       *
       * See: https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#contextreplacementplugin
       * See: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11580
       */
      new ContextReplacementPlugin(
        // The (\\|\/) piece accounts for path separators in *nix and Windows
        /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)src(\\|\/)linker/,
        helpers.root('src'), // location of your src
        {
          // your Angular Async Route paths relative to this root directory
        }
      ),

      /*
       * Plugin: CopyWebpackPlugin
       * Description: Copy files and directories in webpack.
       *
       * Copies project static assets.
       *
       * See: https://www.npmjs.com/package/copy-webpack-plugin
       */
      new CopyWebpackPlugin([{
        from: 'src/assets',
        to: 'assets'
      }]),

      /*
       * Plugin: HtmlWebpackPlugin
       * Description: Simplifies creation of HTML files to serve your webpack bundles.
       * This is especially useful for webpack bundles that include a hash in the filename
       * which changes every compilation.
       *
       * See: https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin
       */
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: 'src/index.html',
        title: METADATA.title,
        chunksSortMode: 'dependency',
        metadata: METADATA,
        inject: 'head'
      }),

      new ScriptExtHtmlWebpackPlugin({
        defaultAttribute: 'defer'
      }),

      /*
       * Plugin: ProvidePlugin
       * Description: Automatically loaded modules. Module (value) is loaded when the identifier (key)
       * is used as free variable in a module. The identifier is filled with the exports of the loaded module.
       *
       * See: https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#provideplugin
       */
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        jQuery: 'jquery',
        $: 'jquery',
        jquery: 'jquery',
        'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
        Tether: 'tether',
        'window.Tether': 'tether',
        Hammer: 'hammerjs/hammer',
        Shuffle: 'shufflejs',
        d3: 'd3',
        Rickshaw: 'rickshaw',
        nv: 'nvd3',
        moment: 'moment',
        fullCalendar: 'fullcalendar',
        Raphael: 'webpack-raphael',
        'window.Raphael': 'webpack-raphael',
        Skycons: 'skycons/skycons',
        Dropzone: 'dropzone'
      }),

      /*
       * Plugin: HtmlHeadConfigPlugin
       * Description: Generate html tags based on javascript maps.
       *
       * If a publicPath is set in the webpack output configuration, it will be automatically added to
       * href attributes, you can disable that by adding a "=href": false property.
       * You can also enable it to other attribute by settings "=attName": true.
       *
       * The configuration supplied is map between a location (key) and an element definition object (value)
       * The location (key) is then exported to the template under then htmlElements property in webpack configuration.
       *
       * Example:
       *  Adding this plugin configuration
       *  new HtmlElementsPlugin({
       *    headTags: { ... }
       *  })
       *
       *  Means we can use it in the template like this:
       *  <%= webpackConfig.htmlElements.headTags %>
       *
       * Dependencies: HtmlWebpackPlugin
       */
      new HtmlElementsPlugin({
        headTags: require('./head-config.common')
      }),

      new LoaderOptionsPlugin({}),

      // Fix Angular 2
      new NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(
        /facade(\\|\/)async/,
        helpers.root('node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/async.js')
      ),
      new NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(
        /facade(\\|\/)collection/,
        helpers.root('node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.js')
      ),
      new NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(
        /facade(\\|\/)errors/,
        helpers.root('node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/errors.js')
      ),
      new NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(
        /facade(\\|\/)lang/,
        helpers.root('node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/lang.js')
      ),
      new NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(
        /facade(\\|\/)math/,
        helpers.root('node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/math.js')
      )
    ],

    /*
     * Include polyfills or mocks for various node stuff
     * Description: Node configuration
     *
     * See: https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#node
     */
    node: {
      global: true,
      crypto: 'empty',
      process: true,
      module: false,
      clearImmediate: false,
      setImmediate: false
    }

  };
}
```

and webpack.prod.js:

```
const helpers = require('./helpers');
const webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge'); // used to merge webpack configs
const commonConfig = require('./webpack.common.js'); // the settings that are common to prod and dev

/**
 * Webpack Plugins
 */
const DedupePlugin = require('webpack/lib/optimize/DedupePlugin');
const DefinePlugin = require('webpack/lib/DefinePlugin');
const IgnorePlugin = require('webpack/lib/IgnorePlugin');
const LoaderOptionsPlugin = require('webpack/lib/LoaderOptionsPlugin');
const NormalModuleReplacementPlugin = require('webpack/lib/NormalModuleReplacementPlugin');
const ProvidePlugin = require('webpack/lib/ProvidePlugin');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('webpack/lib/optimize/UglifyJsPlugin');
const WebpackMd5Hash = require('webpack-md5-hash');
const V8LazyParseWebpackPlugin = require('v8-lazy-parse-webpack-plugin');

/**
 * Webpack Constants
 */
const ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.ENV = 'production';
const HOST = process.env.HOST || 'localhost';
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
const METADATA = webpackMerge(commonConfig({env: ENV}).metadata, {
  host: HOST,
  port: PORT,
  ENV: ENV,
  HMR: false
});

module.exports = function(env) {
  return webpackMerge(commonConfig({env: ENV}), {
    /**
     * Developer tool to enhance debugging
     *
     * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#devtool
     * See: https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/build-performance#sourcemaps
     */
    devtool: 'source-map',

    /**
     * Options affecting the output of the compilation.
     *
     * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output
     */
    output: {

      /**
       * The output directory as absolute path (required).
       *
       * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-path
       */
      path: helpers.root('dist'),

      /**
       * Specifies the name of each output file on disk.
       * IMPORTANT: You must not specify an absolute path here!
       *
       * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-filename
       */
      filename: '[name].[chunkhash].bundle.js',

      /**
       * The filename of the SourceMaps for the JavaScript files.
       * They are inside the output.path directory.
       *
       * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-sourcemapfilename
       */
      sourceMapFilename: '[name].[chunkhash].bundle.map',

      /**
       * The filename of non-entry chunks as relative path
       * inside the output.path directory.
       *
       * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-chunkfilename
       */
      chunkFilename: '[id].[chunkhash].chunk.js'

    },

    /**
     * Add additional plugins to the compiler.
     *
     * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#plugins
     */
    plugins: [
      /**
       * Plugin: WebpackMd5Hash
       * Description: Plugin to replace a standard webpack chunkhash with md5.
       *
       * See: https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-md5-hash
       */
      new WebpackMd5Hash(),
      /**
       * Plugin: DefinePlugin
       * Description: Define free variables.
       * Useful for having development builds with debug logging or adding global constants.
       *
       * Environment helpers
       *
       * See: https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#defineplugin
       */
      // NOTE: when adding more properties make sure you include them in custom-typings.d.ts
      new DefinePlugin({
        'ENV': JSON.stringify(METADATA.ENV),
        'HMR': METADATA.HMR,
        'process.env': {
          'ENV': JSON.stringify(METADATA.ENV),
          'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(METADATA.ENV),
          'HMR': METADATA.HMR,
        }
      }),
      /**
       * Plugin: UglifyJsPlugin
       * Description: Minimize all JavaScript output of chunks.
       * Loaders are switched into minimizing mode.
       *
       * See: https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#uglifyjsplugin
       */
      // NOTE: To debug prod builds uncomment //debug lines and comment //prod lines
      new UglifyJsPlugin({
        beautify: false, //prod
        mangle: { screw_ie8 : true, keep_fnames: true, except: ['$super'] }, //prod
        compress: {
          screw_ie8: true,
          warnings: false,
          conditionals: true,
          unused: true,
          comparisons: true,
          sequences: true,
          dead_code: true,
          evaluate: true,
          if_return: true,
          join_vars: true,
          negate_iife: false // we need this for lazy v8
        }, //prod
        comments: false //prod
      }),

      /**
       * Plugin: NormalModuleReplacementPlugin
       * Description: Replace resources that matches resourceRegExp with newResource
       *
       * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#normalmodulereplacementplugin
       */

      new NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(
        /angular2-hmr/,
        helpers.root('config/empty.js')
      ),

      new NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(
        /zone\.js(\\|\/)dist(\\|\/)long-stack-trace-zone/,
        helpers.root('config/empty.js')
      ),

      // AoT
      // new NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(
      //   /@angular(\\|\/)upgrade/,
      //   helpers.root('config/empty.js')
      // ),
      // new NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(
      //   /@angular(\\|\/)compiler/,
      //   helpers.root('config/empty.js')
      // ),
      // new NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(
      //   /@angular(\\|\/)platform-browser-dynamic/,
      //   helpers.root('config/empty.js')
      // ),
      // new NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(
      //   /dom(\\|\/)debug(\\|\/)ng_probe/,
      //   helpers.root('config/empty.js')
      // ),
      // new NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(
      //   /dom(\\|\/)debug(\\|\/)by/,
      //   helpers.root('config/empty.js')
      // ),
      // new NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(
      //   /src(\\|\/)debug(\\|\/)debug_node/,
      //   helpers.root('config/empty.js')
      // ),
      // new NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(
      //   /src(\\|\/)debug(\\|\/)debug_renderer/,
      //   helpers.root('config/empty.js')
      // ),

      /**
       * Plugin: IgnorePlugin
       * Description: Don’t generate modules for requests matching the provided RegExp.
       *
       * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#ignoreplugin
       */

      // new IgnorePlugin(/angular2-hmr/),

      /**
       * Plugin: CompressionPlugin
       * Description: Prepares compressed versions of assets to serve
       * them with Content-Encoding
       *
       * See: https://github.com/webpack/compression-webpack-plugin
       */
      //  install compression-webpack-plugin
      // new CompressionPlugin({
      //   regExp: /\.css$|\.html$|\.js$|\.map$/,
      //   threshold: 2 * 1024
      // })

      new LoaderOptionsPlugin({
        minimize: true,
        debug: false,
        options: {

          /**
           * Html loader advanced options
           *
           * See: https://github.com/webpack/html-loader#advanced-options
           */
          // TODO: Need to workaround Angular 2's html syntax => #id [bind] (event) *ngFor
          htmlLoader: {
            minimize: true,
            removeAttributeQuotes: false,
            caseSensitive: true,
            customAttrSurround: [
              [/#/, /(?:)/],
              [/\*/, /(?:)/],
              [/\[?\(?/, /(?:)/]
            ],
            customAttrAssign: [/\)?\]?=/]
          }
        }
      })

    ],

    /*
     * Include polyfills or mocks for various node stuff
     * Description: Node configuration
     *
     * See: https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#node
     */
    node: {
      global: true,
      crypto: 'empty',
      process: false,
      module: false,
      clearImmediate: false,
      setImmediate: false
    }
  });
};
```

Sorry if it's TL;DR. I'm fairly new to webpack and I want to be able to serve my angular app through another express server i'm creating that also serves my REST api. I was going to have the webpack production server and my express server in seperate environments but I wanted to see if this was possible in the first place, and if so how.

Answer (score 0):

So there are two ways to do it

1. run express on one port, front-end (webpack) on another...usually in two tabs in your browser (if you want to see your api)
2. Use webpack to proxy the express server, so that you can "run" both on the same port.

Method #2 is more complicated to set up, but the gist of it is:

webpack.config.js
    var config = {

```
  // webpack stuff here ...

  //dev server configuration
  devServer: {

    // ...

    // every request made to 'locahost:8080/api/xxxx' will be proxyfied to 'http://localhost:7000/api/xxxx'
    proxy: {
      "/api/*": {
        target: "http://localhost:7000",
        secure: false,
        rewrite: function(req, options) {
          //you can handle rewrite here if you need to        
        }
      },

    }
  },
 // 
};

module.exports = config;
```

Comment: You can view a more detailed explanation here http://blog.npirotte.be/a-strong-webpack-configuration-part-2/

Comment: I'm currently running this on an ec2 t2.micro instance, I have the webpack server up there already and I had to create a memory swap because the memory would get used up quickly. Would having 2 node servers on there become an issue?

Comment: won't you want to put your static (client-side) stuff on S3 or cloudfront?

Comment: how would I go about doing this?